Is it OK to duplicate information from SO?
If a question has already been asked on SO, is it OK to repost questions with a self-answer (FAQ style) if they are very relevant to RE (e.g. useful questions about disassemblers, assembly language questions, etc)?

No, do not duplicate an already answered SO question unless you need additional information that only the reverse engineering audience can provide. We want to minimize the duplication of content between the sites as much as possible because it is very easy for content to be lost and become out of date.

Actually, no, cross-posting (as in posting the same question on two sites at the same time) is officially strongly discouraged. See Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site? (a more recent thread on the topic with an answer from the then head of SE).
